# Issue with grep in unix

Tags: unix, grep

Here is what the code looks like

```
a1=$(grep -i $movie1 $1 | cut -d ';' -f 2 actors_in_movie1.txt)
a2=$(grep -i $movie2 $1 | cut -d ';' -f 2 actors_in_movie2.txt)
```

When I echo a1 and a2, it prints:
Tom Hanks
Meg Ryan
Tom Hanks
Robin Wright

Tom Hanks is in both movies, and I need it to echo Tom Hanks only once. How do I do this?

Comment: Your commands make little sense.  `cut` is reading from the file, and ignoring its stdin.  The outputs of the `grep` are totally ignored.

Comment: @bluedawn1131, Please add values of $movie1 and $movie2. also provide the 1-2 lines from both the text files.